# Is OCI TAO or DOC Group TAO implementation best to use with OpenDDS?

Tags: tao, opendds

I'm doing some research in using [OpenDDS](https://opendds.org/). In the [configure script](https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/blob/master/configure) I came across the option to use different TAO implementations.

- OCI's TAO
- DOC Group TAO

I've read OCI does more testing and has direct bug fixing. On the other hand I saw a library TAOX11 which adds C++11 support to DOC Group TAO, what OCI TAO doesn't have. This feature is very handy but in my opinion the solution with the least problems is using OCI's TAO, because OCI also developed OpenDDS.

Now my question is, does anybody has experience with the two libraries and knows which implementation I use best with OpenDDS?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the DOCGroup version because it is more up to date and more tested due to the community effort. All CI builds for OpenDDS are using the DOCGroup version, see http://scoreboard.ociweb.com/oci-dds.html for all OpenDDS builds and http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/scoreboard/integrated.html for all ACE/TAO/CIAO/DDS builds.

Comment: Just to confirm, the most tested version (doc_group) is not the default of the configure script?

Comment: yes, OCI still prefers to ship their fork, tried to switch it to DOC group already a few times